# Copy multiple files from hadoop to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have couple of files in Hadoop directory. I am trying to copy files from hadoop directory to s3 bucket.

List of files

sample1.txt

sample2.txt

sample3.txt

I want to copy all files at once

```
 aws s3 cp *.txt s3://bucket-name/samples/
```

It shows me error

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
aws s3 cp . s3://<bucket-name> --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
aws s3 cp <Hadoop-Dir-Path> s3://<bucket-name> --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"
```

Or you can use sync as well :

```
aws s3 sync . s3://<bucket-name> --exclude "*" --include "file.*"
```

Note that, by default, all files are included. This means that providing only an --include filter will not change what files are transferred. --include will only re-include files that have been excluded from an --exclude filter. If you only want to upload files with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then re-include the files with the particular extension. This command will upload only files ending with .txt.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

[AWS Documenation for sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)